# Why won't this while loop stop?

Tags: c++

I can't understand why this while loop isn't stopping once the end condition is matched?

The idea is the user inputs a 5 digit integer and can type anything else to terminate the input process. But

```
bool noerror(true);
int n(0),part2temp;
vector<int> part2;

while(noerror){
    cout << "Please enter the 5 integer (x to stop)" << endl;
    cin >> part2temp;
    part2.push_back(part2temp);
    n++;

    if (cin.fail()||part2temp>99999||part2temp<10000){
        cout << "End condition matched" << endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(10);
        noerror=(false);
    }
}
cout << "escaped loop" << part2[n] << endl;
```

I get the output to the screen from the IF part of the loop when I type in x for example but for some reason changing the bool value does not terminate the loop and the text "escaped loop" is never shown on screen.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Several things: first, indexes in a vector go from [0...n), so `part2[n]` indexes one beyond the end.  And second, you don't need to keep track of the number of elements in the vector, `std::vector` does this for you; use `part2.size()` to get the value.  And third, supposing the vector non-empty, `part2.back()` is the simplest way of accessing the last element.

Comment: What end condition (you have three) is not meeting your expectations? All of them??

Comment: Also, you should check for failure _before_ accessing `part2temp` (i.e. before the `push_back`).  (And you should probably define `part2tmp` in the loop, and not outside of it.)

Comment: You can set a breakpoint in a debugger, in the `if` block, and when hit you can step to see what happens, and also examine the values of all relevant variables.

Answer (score 3):

There is undefined behaviour as the `part2[n]` is going one beyond the bounds of the `vector`, and may be the reason the output of the following line of code never appears:

```
cout << "escaped loop" << part2[n] << endl;
```

giving the impression the loop does not exit. If the loop executes just once then `n == 1` and there will be one element only in the `vector` named `part2`, which means only `part2[0]` is valid. To confirm this use `vector::at()` and wrap it in a `try{}catch(std::out_of_range&)` block:

```
try
{
    cout << "escaped loop" << part2.at(n) << endl;
}
catch (std::out_of_range const&)
{
    std::cerr << "Access out of range\n";
}
```

To correct, confirm the `vector` is not [`empty()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/empty) and use either `[n - 1]`  or [`vector.back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/back).

Comment: Ive removed that part from the code as it wasn't necessary, thanks for pointing it out though, im getting mixed up with programming languages..

Comment: @user2054823, it is unclear to me if the problem is now resolved? BTW, unless `noerror` is required elsewhere you can just `break` from the `while` inside the `if` and `noerror` variable is no longer required.

Comment: @hmjd Don't recommend using `break` to an inexperienced programmer.  Globally, it's almost never a good idea.  A better solution would be to create a function for read with prompt, and loop on that: something like `while ( getlineWithPrompt( prompt, line ) )` (where `getlineWithPrompt` returns `std::cin`).

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using `cin.ignore()`?  As written, `cin.ignore()` will only return after having read 10 characters.  Do you really want the user to have to enter 10 characters after the input (before he enters a new line)?  If your input is line oriented, the usual procedure is to use `std::getline` to read the entire line, then parse it using `std::istringstream`; alternatively, you can use something like `std::cin.ignore( MAX_INT, '\n' );`, which will ignore up to the next new line.

Comment: I've fixed the problem, it turns out it didn't like:

    cin.ignore(10);

and was never actually getting to the line where the bool was set to false. Im not sure why this was a problem but it was solved by changing it to:

    cin.ignore(10,'\n');

If anyone could explain that to me i would be grateful, thanks for all the help so far!

Comment: @user2054823 As I said in my answer, `cin.ignore(10)` will _not_ return until it has been able to read 10 characters (or it encounters end of file).  And `cin.ignore( 10, '\n' );` will still ignore at most 10 characters; if the user enters 20 blanks after the number, you probably won't get the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

Change

> cin.ignore(10);

to

> cin.ignore(10,'\n');

then the loop exits, try it!